# What does "%-6d" mean in printf

Tags: c

I don't understand what `"%-6d"` mean in `printf`.

For example, If x=3, then `printf(%-6d);` prints `"3    "` (minus the quotes) Why?

I was expecting that it will prints a tab and then `3`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: To more clearly see what is happening, use `"|%-6d|"`

Comment: And [Format specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160).

Comment: printf doesn't use tabs for padding. No idea where you got that idea? If you want a tab followed by `3`,  you can use `printf( "\t%d\n", x );`

Answer (score 1):

The `-` in the `%-6d` format specifier indicates the number is to be *left-aligned*, rather than right. You don't see the whitespace inserted because nothing is printed *after* your number.

If you tried `printf("%-6d!\n", 3)` you'd see as a result when running the program:

```
$ ./a.out
3     !
$
```

To right-align, simply leave the `-` out: `%6d`

```
$ ./a.out
     3!
$
```